# Identity of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How would I show that there is a ring $R$ with identity $1_R$ and a subring $S$ not containing $1_R$, but such that $S$ has its own identity $1_S$ not equal to $1_R$?

Comment: Your problem is asking for an example of a ring with such a subring. Consider $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and subring $\{0,2,4 \}$. In the subring $4$ is acting as the multiplicative identity.

Comment: By looking for an example. You may look at quotient rings ${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$ in particular for some accessible ones.

Comment: @BillCook Please don't clutter up the comments with answers: there is an answer section for that! :)

Comment: I answered this in your [prior related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/369561/23500) Did you miss it?

Comment: The same question was asked already many times on math.SE.

Answer (score 3):

You can take $R = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $S = \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\} \subset R$. Then $1_R = (1,1) \neq (1,0) = 1_S$.

Comment: what exactly are the elements in Z x {0}, would they be all elements of the form (0,0),(1,0),(2,0)...ect

Comment: @user72195 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example (related to the one by **Alex P.**) is given by the rings of matrices
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} : a \in F
\right\}
= S \subseteq
R = \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} : a, b, c, d \in F
\right\}
$$
where $F$ might be $\Bbb{Z}, \Bbb{Q}, \Bbb{R}, \dots$.

Here
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} 
= 1_{S} \ne 1_{R} = 
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The rings of the form $(\mathbb Z_n,\oplus,\odot)$ are quite simple, so let us try them.

If $R=\mathbb Z_n$ then $1_R=1$. A candidate for $1_S$ can be only an element such that $1_S\odot 1_S=1_S$.

In $\mathbb Z_2$, $\mathbb Z_3$, $\mathbb Z_5$ we do not have non-trivial subrings.

In $\mathbb Z_4$ the only element such that $a\odot a=a$ is $a=1$.

What about $R=\mathbb Z_6$? Could you find a subring $S$ with the required properties?